# Why is loading specific WMS giving me CORS error, while others work

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cors

A client wants to dynamically add and remove WMS Layers to a web application from a governmental source.

The code to do this is a simple as it can get:

```
//layerObj has a property id, that contains the url as a string
var layer = new WMSLayer(layerObj.id);
//wait until the infos have been retrieved
layer.on("load", function(i) {
    var visibleLayers = layer.layerInfos.map(function(x) {
        return x.name;
    });
    layer.visibleLayers = visibleLayers;
    //update the store and add the layer to the coresponding item, so we can later on remove it form the map, without
    //actually querying the map
    var item = _store.query({ id: layerObj.id })[0];
    item["layer"] = layer;
    item["title"] = layer.title;
    _store.put(item, { overwrite: true });
    //add to map
    map.addLayer(layer);
    //add to list
    addToLayerList(layer);
});
```

I am using http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=2&gdz_anz_zeile=5&gdz_user_id=0 as a source to test different WMS. The first table under "Beispiele" gives you an actual url to implement.

- http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dtk200 is working
- http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dtk1000 is working
- http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dgm1000 is working

but once I get to `http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_webatlasde.light`

I am receiving the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_webatlasde.light?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities. 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, *', but only one is
allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Why would this work for most of the WMS available, but fail for one or 2?

Comment: When you read the GetCapabilities in a browser does it refer to localhost in any online resource URL?

Comment: @Marco did you resolve this? If so, how did you get around it? Cheers.